# Can we physically explain superconductor mean field order parameter (gap function) as Cooper pair wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity

We usually define mean field order parameter (gap function) in BCS theory
$$
\Delta(r_1,r_2)_{s,s'} = \langle GS | \hat{\psi}_s(r_1)\hat{\psi}_{s'}(r_2) |GS\rangle,
$$
where $\hat{\psi}_s(r_1)$ is field operator of electron on position $r_1$ with spin $s$ and $|GS\rangle$ is ground state of a superconductor.

Can we understand this quantity as a wavefucntion of a Cooper pair just as solution of two electrons interacting with each other via an attractive potential?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know my answer make sense or not what i understand about that order parameters given by

> `wave function mod square it represents the copper pair forming probability density which is zero above some critical temperature and critical fields.`

Now the formation copper pair is little bit tricker but this is how i imagine with classical pictures.  Imagine +ve charge uniform density lattice . Now imagine two electron moving parallel to each other one of them slightly behind other. Since electron is negatively charge it will attract near by +ve core resulting a compression like mesh  we call that creation of phonon represents  as 'psi+' opperator acted on vacuum.  Due to that a higher dense +ve charge density occurs resulting attractive force on electron slightly behind it. Now the oscillation is in sound velocity range while electron moving much faster than sound   . Even electron not their the phonon created will be gonna continue their resulting attracting in other electron thats electron phonon electron interaction make the Cooper pair possible

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).